# Customize system combined bar /navigation bar for Android tablet (bottom)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigationbar

I would like to override (add more buttons that would take me to several activities/fragments) to the system Navigation Bar on a tablet (according to this [android ui-overview](http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html) it is a "Combined bar" (for tablets)
Is there a way to do this?

I couldn't find a Navigation class in the android.app package, like ActionBar.

If adding buttons to the combined/navigation bar is not possible, I think there are several options, but I'd like to explore this first:
- use the action bar on top instead
- add a bottom bar above the navigation bar (not really fine, since it would be on top of the combined bar), like they are showing here:
[Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)

Thanks a lot, 
Cristian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this?

No. The only thing you can add to the system bar are `Notifications`, which are not meant for this sort of navigation.

> If adding buttons to the combined/navigation bar is not possible, I think there are several options, but I'd like to explore this first: - use the action bar on top instead - add a bottom bar above the navigation bar (not really fine, since it would be on top of the combined bar), like they are showing here: Action Bar

If you are referring to the section titled "Layout Considerations for Split Action Bars", that is referred to as a "split action bar", and can be enabled on an `<activity>` via `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`. However, that will only take effect for `-small`/`-normal` screens in portrait orientation. Your buttons will automatically be placed in the action bar at the top of the screen in other circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, CommonsWare, I appreciate it. I was kind of expecting that (not being possible) And I like the Android CommonsWare books. We're already looking to do it inside the ActionBar.