# removing or overriding certain items from action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Below is an image of the action bar on a Samsung Tab2 action bar running 4.0.3 android ICS

[image]

from left to right we have the "back, home, recent apps, screenshot, mini-app launcher, and system menu" buttons.  Im certain i am not using the correct names for all these which is why i listed them from left to right along with the above image.

I know i can override the the functionality of "back" using:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
          // Do something custom here
    }
```

i also know that i can NOT override or remove the home button but i was wondering if i could remove  or override the "recent apps", "take screen shot", and "mini app launcher"

would be nice if i could remove the back as well..

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11768727/1134705

Comment: The `ActionBar` is not what you are referring to ([see here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)), the `ActionBar` can be manipulated, however you are showing one of the System Bars called the [Navigation Bar](http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html), which cannot be manipulated (in reference to the View) unless you are writing a custom ROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just rolled out almost 100 GTab2s and have another 1,000 on order. This is something we've looked into extensively, especially in regards to screenshot and the minitab bloat. You can not remove the screenshot button, nor minitab, unless you root the device and modify the system image. (in short: you can't). 
You could "remove" the home button by implementing your own launcher and getting rid of touchwiz.

FWIW, Samsung's B2B folks have been very helpful in supporting our efforts, even at our relatively small quantities. If you were building, say, a kiosk app around the GTab2, you might be able to get them to supply you with a less bloated image.

```
static public final String[] pkgs_GT_P3113_LH2 = new String[] { "com.kobobooks.samsung.android", 
                                                                "com.netflix.mediaclient",
                                                                "com.nim.discovery",
                                                                "com.osp.app.signin",
                                                                "com.peel.app",
                                                                "com.samsung.mediahub",
                                                                "com.samsung.music",
                                                                "com.sec.android.app.gamehub",
                                                                "com.sec.android.app.minimode.res",
                                                                "com.sec.android.app.music",
                                                                "com.sec.android.app.readershub",
                                                                "com.sec.android.app.samsungapps",
                                                                "com.sec.android.app.sns3",
                                                                "com.sec.android.daemonapp.ap.yahoonews",
                                                                "com.sec.android.daemonapp.ap.yahoostock.stockclock",
                                                                "com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.yahoonews",
                                                                "com.sec.android.widgetapp.at.yahoostock.stockclock",
                                                                "com.sec.android.widgetapp.minipaper",
                                                                "com.sec.chaton",
                                                                "com.sec.minimode.music",
                                                                "com.sec.pcw",
                                                                "com.tgrape.android.radar",
                                                                "com.zinio.samsung.android" };
```

Comment: Would that image require rooting?  cause we are making kiosk tablets and our client will not let us root

Comment: It would require rooting to adapt your own image. If you get Samsung's support, they could sign the image for you, and it wouldn't require rooting. Be sure to disable things like Samsung's "-hub" apps and Samsung Account as well. Our's is not a kiosk app, but for many first-time tablet users, Samsung went overboard on what they preload on the devices.

Comment: can you tell me what the package name is for "-hub" and what it is exactly?  i am trying to hack some stuff because the client is very reluctant to go to samsung for a custom rom..  i managed to kill the screen_capture as it was easy to pick out in a list of running processes on the tablet.. i desperately want to find the package that is the ^ button in the middle of the above image (opening a tray of samsung mini apps)

Comment: @erik, I edited the answer with the list of packages I disabled on the devices. Look at the com.sec.android.app.gamehub/.readershub/.music, and com.samsung.mediahub/.music.

Comment: Also, the minimode stuff is in /system, so you'd have to be rooted to remove those. I know, it sucks. Did you say you permanently got rid of screen capture without root? How? Whenever I kill it, it comes back.

Comment: well i had built a service class that just killed it repeatedly with a timerTask, i know that is such a HACK.. but then i realized it can be removed in the settings>display

Comment: Oh... my... I never looked there. I'm adding that to the procedures for device preload. THANK YOU!